# How do ZFS snapshots use space in practice?

Tags: freebsd, snapshot, zfs

1. Created a snapshot
2. Deleted a huge file
3. Delta is still 0 (snapshot not using anymore space) in `zfs list` for past three snapshots

Should the delta or used space not be the size of the deleted file. I know ZFS is COW but I'm confused as to why I can't rollback the `/usr/home/xxxx` child

```
# ls /home/xxxxx/testing12345.txt 
/home/xxxxx/testing12345.txt
# ls -alh /home/xxxxx/testing12345.txt                                                                                                                                 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  xxxxx   254M Aug 28 00:06 /home/xxxxx/testing12345.txt
# zfs list -rt snapshot tank1/usr/home/xxxxx
NAME                                        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@myRecursiveSnapshot   291M      -   804M  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@devEnv                 71K      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@xfce                     0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@testhome                 0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@testagain               1K      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@27082015                 0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@270820150                0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@2708201501               0      -  1.39G  -
# 
# 
# 
# 
# zfs snapshot -r tank1@28082015                                                                                                                                        
# zfs list -rt snapshot tank1/usr/home/xxxxx                                                                                                                           
NAME                                        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@myRecursiveSnapshot   291M      -   804M  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@devEnv                 71K      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@xfce                     0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@testhome                 0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@testagain               1K      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@27082015                 0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@270820150                0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@2708201501               0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@28082015                 0      -  1.39G  -
# rm /home/xxxxx/testing12345.txt                                                                                                                                      
# zfs list -rt snapshot tank1/usr/home/xxxxx                                                                                                                           
NAME                                        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@myRecursiveSnapshot   291M      -   804M  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@devEnv                 71K      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@xfce                     0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@testhome                 0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@testagain               1K      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@27082015                 0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@270820150                0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@2708201501               0      -  1.39G  -
tank1/usr/home/xxxxx@28082015                 0      -  1.39G  -
#
```

I've been tried rolling back using various snapshots the `/usr`, `/usr/home`, and `/usr/home/xxxx` directories. I've read the FreeBSD forums, the handbook, and I've also tried rolling back just `tank1@[snapshot name]--all` to no effect. 
Something odd, when I change files in `/usr/home/xxxxx` files in the hidden `.zfs/snapshots/[snapshot name]/usr/home/xxxxx` directory change as well.

Comment: if you are going to vote this down, please leave a comment with an explanation so that I may correct the question. A vote down without a comment is not particularly helpful.

Comment: I should mention that I am able to successfully `zfs send` and `zfs receive` to a backup pool.

Comment: Are you looking for an refference to a document explaining it or would be satisfied by an practice that is confirming the behaving in the bsd os code?

Comment: I've been following the BSD handbook, so I need not reference material--I'm looking for the answer as to why the snapshot does not grow in allotted size when I delete the large file from the snapshot-ed volume and why I can't restore it when I follow the restoration steps quite diligently, @Zaibis

Comment: @Zaibis, I'm also looking for a canonical answer as to how, when and how much space zfs snapshots account for--I believe this answer followed by a quick explanation of what I'm doing wrong here or why my restoration isn't working would suffice for the bounty

Comment: "*when I change files in /usr/home/xxxxx files in the hidden .zfs/snapshots/[snapshot name]/usr/home/xxxxx directory change as well*" <= What kind of changes are you experiencing? Because when I do this locally, the existing snapshot does not change a bit.

Comment: I'm seeing changes in .zfs snapshot dir corresponding to my actions taken in the actual dir

Comment: @sjt003 This is very strange and  --as noted-- I cannot confirm this locally. I would also consider such a behavior simply a (critical) bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command to see space used for all snapshots of a vdev - relevant property you want is usedsnap:

```
zfs list -o name,used,avail,refer,creation,usedds,usedsnap,origin,compression,compressratio,refcompressratio,mounted,atime,lused
```

I've added a few more properties since I use compression on my zfs pools.

zfs snapshots directories are read-only by the way.

You said you cannot roll back? If that's the case specify -r or -R and possibly -f if you have clones, sample:

```
zfs rollback -r poolname/dataset@oldersnaphot
zfs rollback -R poolname/dataset@oldersnaphot
```

**Read the manual before issuing zfs rollback**:

> ```
>        -r
>            Destroy any snapshots and bookmarks more recent than the one specified.
>        -R
>            Recursively destroy any more recent snapshots and bookmarks, as well as any clones of those snapshots.
>        -f
>            Used with the -R option to force an unmount of any clone file systems that are to be destroyed.
> ```